# How to make flex items take full width of container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, computer-science

My flex items don't take full width in container. I've something like below. Please see this.

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfBoP.png)

Here is what I want to achieve.
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdF8R.png)

I've tried adding flex-column. But not work.

In my index.html

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-column">

                <div class="card my-daily-expense-card my-bg-danger">
            <span class="mb-1 date">29.4.2019</span>
            <hr>
            <small class="label text-secondary">Total Expense:</small>
            <h2 class="mt-1 mb-0 amount">50000 ks</h2>
        </div>
                . . .
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my css,

```css
.my-daily-expense-card {
    margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
    max-width: 14rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 0.60rem;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

.card {
    border: 0;
}
```

> I want to achieve my flex items touch to the right boundary of container (I want my flex items take full width of container but let each width be still in the image).

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: That's. [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/Y9o1Mnt.png)

Comment: Did you try assigning the class col-auto to it ?

Comment: you can use bootstrap property `row no-gutters` it will stretch the column end to end

Comment: @XxSTREKxX [Here](https://i.imgur.com/yXQqJYP.png) That's not what I want to achieve. I think it need to be done with some javascript.

Comment: @prasannapurohit Not working. I want each flex-items take some paddings equally enough to stretch the full width of the container.

Comment: try adding  justify-content:space-between  to the parent div (d-flex flex-wrap flex-column) @HtetPhyoNaing

Comment: I hope I understood your requirement. you can see the code I given below it may help you

Comment: @AmareshSM It seems working [here](https://i.imgur.com/O43oi00.png). But I want space between items keep equal. I just want to give some calculated paddings to each items.

Comment: @HtetPhyoNaing Try using justify-content:space-around

Answer (score 0):

it may lengthy process, but I hope it will make satisfaction to you.

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="card my-daily-expense-card my-bg-danger">
      <span class="mb-1 date">29.4.2019</span>
      <hr>
      <small class="label text-secondary">Total Expense:</small>
      <h2 class="mt-1 mb-0 amount">50000 ks</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="card my-daily-expense-card my-bg-danger">
      <span class="mb-1 date">29.4.2019</span>
      <hr>
      <small class="label text-secondary">Total Expense:</small>
      <h2 class="mt-1 mb-0 amount">50000 ks</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="card my-daily-expense-card my-bg-danger">
      <span class="mb-1 date">29.4.2019</span>
      <hr>
      <small class="label text-secondary">Total Expense:</small>
      <h2 class="mt-1 mb-0 amount">50000 ks</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="card my-daily-expense-card my-bg-danger">
      <span class="mb-1 date">29.4.2019</span>
      <hr>
      <small class="label text-secondary">Total Expense:</small>
      <h2 class="mt-1 mb-0 amount">50000 ks</h2>
    </div>
  </div>`
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="card my-daily-expense-card my-bg-danger">
      <span class="mb-1 date">29.4.2019</span>
      <hr>
      <small class="label text-secondary">Total Expense:</small>
      <h2 class="mt-1 mb-0 amount">50000 ks</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="card my-daily-expense-card my-bg-danger">
      <span class="mb-1 date">29.4.2019</span>
      <hr>
      <small class="label text-secondary">Total Expense:</small>
      <h2 class="mt-1 mb-0 amount">50000 ks</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

make like this 6 columns so it will get the same size for every column. here I used as an example of your single code. you may try it with your original code

Comment: I don't want fixed column width to items. Thanks for your answer.